# What are the challenges?

Tags: dungeonland

What are the challenges in Dungeonland?  I turned them on for the first time (Cannibal Kingdom, Casual) and see 3 but the challenge icons, but the names are rather unhelpful.  The Challenges I found are:

- Wrath of the Sheep God
- No Mercy
- Thirst

Are they the same every time?  What do they do?

[image: Zoomed Screenshot]